# Timestamp converted to UTC while loading to parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, parquet, timestamp-with-timezone

I am loading data to parquet through spark.

```
dataFrame.write.parquet(path)
```

My data have a timestamp column while writing to parquet it is actually converting timestamp to UTC timezone and then storing.

**actual time** -------   2020-10-21 00:00:00.000
**UTC time**---------                  2020-10-21T05:30:00.000+05:30

I see spark conf is set to UTC timezone.`spark.sql.session.timeZone`
Is there any way to turn off this conversion?

I want to load timestamp as is without converting it to any other timezone. how do i do that?

Comment: did you set spark.session.timezone?

Comment: In my cluster it is set to UTC

Comment: As an alternative option, you can store it as `long`.

Answer (score 4):

See documentation here:

https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html

> When writing timestamp values out to non-text data sources like Parquet, the values are just instants (like timestamp in UTC) that have no time zone information. If you write and read a timestamp value with a different session time zone, you may see different values of the hour, minute, and second fields, but they are the same concrete time instant.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example adding a code snippet how to solve the question might help.